# CDF after using weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots $  be a sequence of infinite independent and identically distributed random variables, where $X_i\sim U[0,1]$.

Let $D_n = \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2 + \ldots + X_n^2}$ be a random variable. What is the the value of the following cumulative distribution function at the point $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$:  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}F_{\frac{Dn}{\sqrt{n}}} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)= \text{?}$$

Is it $1$ because all CDFs are right continuous or is it $\frac12$ because of the delta like function the distribution is like at $n=\infty$?

Comment: I doubt the weak law is strong enough to settle this. It says the distribution of $D_n/\sqrt 3$ is concentrated near $1/\sqrt 3,$ but within the small region where most of it is concentrated, how is it distributed? That's more than what the weak law tells you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the Weak Law of Large Numbers, it's the Central Limit Theorem.

$\mathbb E[X_n^2] = 1/3$.
By the Central Limit Theorem, $Y_n = \sqrt{n}(D_n^2/n - 1/3)$ tends in distribution to $\mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $X_n^2$.  In particular

$$ \mathbb F_{\frac{D_n}{\sqrt{n}}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \mathbb P\left(\frac{D_n}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \mathbb P\left(Y_n \le 0\right) \to \mathbb P(Z \le 0) = \frac12$$

Comment: In other words, it's not "$1/2$ because of the delta-like function", but $1/2$ for a different reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Doesn't it contradict the rule that the CDF is right continious? Since it is not right continious at 1/sqrt(3)?

Comment: You're talking about a limit of CDF's, not a CDF of a particular random variable.